# Merging 2D array by ID - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hello guys I am stuck for this kind of merging of arrays:

**Sample Array**

```
Array(
     [0] => Array(
            'id' => '1',
            'task' => 'Task 1.0'
         ),
     [1] => Array(
            'id' => '1',
            'task' => 'Task 1.1'
         ),
     [2] => Array(
            'id' => '2',
            'task' => 'Task 2.0'
         ),
     [3] => Array(
            'id' => '2',
            'task' => 'Task 2.1'
         )
)
```

**Expected Result**

```
Array(
     [0] => Array(
            'id' => '1',
            'task' => array(
                      [0] => 'Task 1.0',
                      [1] => 'Task 1.1' 
                   )
         ),
     [1] => Array(
            'id' => '2',
            'task' => array(
                      [0] => 'Task 2.0',
                      [1] => 'Task 2.1' 
                   )
         )
)
```

How can I do this kind of merging?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Comment: Seems good question i have tried but can't resolved.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might not be the best solution, but i would consider it as an aproach:

```
$oldArray = array (
    0 => array(
           'id' => '1',
           'task' => 'Task 1.0'
        ),
    1 => array(
           'id' => '1',
           'task' => 'Task 1.1'
        ),
    2 => array(
           'id' => '2',
           'task' => 'Task 2.0'
        ),
    3 => array(
           'id' => '2',
           'task' => 'Task 2.1'
        )
);

$newArray = array();

foreach( $oldArray as $array ) {
    if( !isset( $newArray[$array["id"]] ) ) {
        $newArray[$array["id"]] = array( "id" => $array["id"] );
    }

    $newArray[$array["id"]]["task"][] = $array["task"];
}

// reset the temp keys
$newArray = array_values( $newArray );
```

Edited: forgot "tasks" in $newArray[$array["id"]]["task"][] = $array["task"];, made an edit again